# Scraping for research projects: some issues

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I am scraping some websites for a research project, I am encountering issues that I think might be useful to many SO users.
Given a well-defined topic (e.g. bird-watching or astro-physics), basically my objectives are:

- Identify important websites that spread these ideas
- Crawl a representative sample of these websites
- Perform some network analysis and thematic analysis of the data (e.g. topic models)
- Publish the results in an academic venue, without publishing any of the crawled data

To achieve this goal, I am finding the following obstacles:

- **Sampling method**: obviously, it's impossible to establish the boundaries of the sites of interest. As it is impossible to know the size of the dataset, how can I establish the representativeness of the sample? I can crawl 10K, 1M, or 10M pages without knowing when I should stop.
- **Detection/banning issue**: my crawler, based on [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org), is following `robots.txt` and tries not to hammer servers by introducing increasing delays between the requests, starting from 25ms. However, a lot of servers still detect the crawler and block it. In this sense, my sampling process is totally biased by what servers cut me off.
- **Legal issues**: this is clearly a gray area, but I feel that if I don't publish the actual pages I should be on the safe side. What precautions can I take to avoid upsetting people, especially if the results of the study annoy some website owners?

It would be nice to outline a methodology for researchers, because I am sure that many people encounter these problems as soon as they start crawling a non-trivial number of pages.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: "Legal issues: this is clearly a gray area" Not as gray as you might think. You might want to read up on copyright law.

Comment: Do you have any pointer to relevant documents? The websites are hosted in different countries.

Comment: Some best practices on how to avoid getting banned: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned